# Genymotion: Initialize engine : Failed (moments ago)

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, virtualbox

as shown in the title , I have this problem which made me *sick*
the problem is as follows:

I use Android studio **V 1.3.2** and I installed `Genymotion` **V 2.5.4**
`Genymotion` works fine when I start the main program , but when I add the plugin to Android studio , it gives me the error

```
Genymotion:Initialize Engine: Failed
```

As I understood from suggested solutions that the problem is in the plugin itself the plugin is V 1.0.5

I tried all versions of virtualBox to solve this compatibility problem but I couldn't so I started to doubt it as compatibility issue

I tried these versions of virtualBox

1. V 4.2.32
2. V 4.3.28
3. V 4.2.20
4. V 4.2.0
5. V 4.1.36
6. V 5.0.4

none of them worked with the plugin
could anyone please help me?

Comment: remove plugin , genymotion works fine without any additions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Genymotion without the Android studio plug in.

Start Genymotion virtual device directly and then run the application using Android studio. This will prompt you to select the virtual device on which the application should run. The Genymotion virtual device will be listed there.